# Wrong values for double in swift

Tags: ios, swift, double, addition

I have string value and converting to double value for adding it. But it shows different values when debugging. While using print statement it shows correct values, but when using "po" command in console shows different, so getting different results then expected one.

```
    let stringValue = "83.84"
    let doubleValue = Double(stringValue)
    let floatValue = Float(stringValue)

    let decimalArray: Array<Double> = [doubleValue!, doubleValue!, doubleValue!]
    let test1 = decimalArray.reduce(0, combine: +)

    let floatArray: Array<Float> = [floatValue!, floatValue!, floatValue!]
    let test2 = floatArray.reduce(0, combine: +)

    print(test1)
    print(test2)
```

I have attached the image of the console. Please let me know how this can be resolved.
[image]

Comment: If you want to compare float numbers, do not use Float or Double. There are plenty of articles explaining why. You should use NSDecimalNumber instead or store the decimals as Int.

Comment: That's how binary floating point arithmetic works. About 15 digits precision for double, and much less for float. What's wrong is not the code, but your expectations. And this is the same in C, C++, Objective-C, Java and so on.

Answer (score -3):

I think you are using `po` before it's properly converting. put just one `breakpoint` at last line i.e. at `print(test2)` and then check.